# Magento extension to identify country and show popup/shipping message

Tags: extensions

we are looking for a Magento extension to identify country and show popup/shipping message. Pref. without too much pressure on performance.

Something like they do on this site:
www.brooksbrothers.com
and this site have it
shop.nordstrom.com

**Question**: Is this programmed? or would extensions be available?

I know pop-up extensions exist. But there are just [so many](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enNL609NL609&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=magento%20identify%20country%20popup%20extension) and so many examples. And none seem to do exactly the above.

Help appreciated